# Giving instructions to an executable in UNIX?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, unix, script

I'm pretty new at this, so excuse me if this is too easy.
The thing is, I have a bunch of instructions stored in a text file named: 'FTIG_dldStruct.txt' and I want to write them all into an executable named: 'STP'. I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set +H

./STP # This is the executable

for i in {1..586} 
    do
        sed -n -e "$i"p FTIG_dldStruct.txt
done
```

My program runs the executable, and it asks me for input like this:

STP> # I want the instructions here, but my for loop is not working until I exit the executable.

Comment: Welcome Herber - scripting is totally on topic here as on several other sites. No need to go elsewhere unless you don’t get any good answers in 2 weeks time or so. That being said - no worries you are new. Can you edit and clarify - executable normally means a compiled program and scripts / interpreted programs are bash scripts. Are you saying you need to run a program and then process a file when the program ends?

Comment: @MatthewBarclay Scripting questions (both for AppleScript and for shell scripts) are perfectly on-topic on AD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you want to send some number (586?) lines from `FTIG_dldStruct.txt` to the `./STP` command? If so, assuming `./STP` reads from standard input as is typical, that may look like:

```
head -n 586 FTIG_dldStruct.txt | ./STP
```

As pointed out in the comments to pass the entire contents of the file that would be:

```
./STP < FTIG_dldStruct.txt
```

Various pipelines are also possible, perhaps to filter out comments (here arbitrarily defined as lines beginning with `#`) with `grep`:

```
grep -v '^#' FTIG_dldStruct.txt | ./STP
```

If you need `./STP` to stick around after those commands are entered so the program can be interacted with, that's a more complicated issue and typically requires an `expect` script that in turn wraps around `./STP`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect -f
set filehandle [open "FTIG_dldStruct.txt"]
set maxlines 586
spawn -noecho ./STP
while {[gets $filehandle line] >= 0 && $maxlines > 0} {
    # wait for prompt from program
    expect -ex "STP>"
    send "$line\r"
    incr maxlines -1
}
# turn interaction with the program over to the user
interact
```

This code would need to be saved to a file and made executable like any other script on unix. `expect` has also been made available as a library in various other programming languages.

Comment: If you want to send the entire contents of FTIG_dldStruct.txt, it's even easier: `./STP <FTIG_dldStruct.txt`.